# C# how to get directory info with avoiding readonly files

Tags: directoryinfo

how can i get directory info without getting readonly file or folders here is my code but this when the file or folder is readonly returns a error!

```
var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path_Tb_Path.Text);
var entries = dirinfo.GetFileSystemInfos("**", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Access to the path 'F:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18' is denied.

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled